# Set Gatling report name in Jenkins pipeline througt taurus

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gatling, taurus

I'm writing a declarative jenkins pipeline and I'm facing problems with gatling reports:

[image]

Mean response time trend is not correct, Is there a way to replace following cloud of dots by a curve ?

Extracts from my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('perf') {
  steps {
    bzt params: './taurus/scenario.yml', generatePerformanceTrend: false, printDebugOutput: true
    perfReport configType: 'PRT', graphType: 'PRT', ignoreFailedBuilds: true, modePerformancePerTestCase: true, modeThroughput: true, sourceDataFiles: 'results.xml'
    dir ("taurus/results") {
      gatlingArchive()
    }
  }
}
```

Extract from my *scenario.yml*:

```
modules:
  gatling:
    path:      ./bin/gatling.sh
    java-opts: -Dgatling.core.directory.data=./data
```

In *scenario.yml*, I tried to set `gatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName` :

```
java-opts: -Dgatling.core.directory.data=./data -Dgatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName=./my_scenario
```

In this case it replace only *gatling* by *my_scenario*, but huge number is already present.

Comment: bzt is synonym for taurus, I think tag bzt should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to solve this problem, but it's not simple since it involves an extension of the taurus code.

The problem is [here](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.9.6/bzt/modules/gatling.py#L309), at line 309 of the file *gatling.py* in taurus repo. It explicitly add a prefix 'gatling-' to find a gatling report.

However, parameter `-Dgatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName=./my_scenario` in  file *scenario.yml* change this prefix by *my_scenario*. What I will describe below is a way to extend taurus in order to quickly extends.

**Create a file *./extensions/gatling.py* with this code to extend class GatlingExecutor:**

```
from bzt.modules.gatling import GatlingExecutor, DataLogReader

class GatlingExecutorExtension(GatlingExecutor):
    def __init__(self):
        GatlingExecutor.__init__(self)

    def prepare(self):
        # From method bzt.modules.gatling.GatlingExecutor:prepare, copy code before famous line 309
        # Replace line 309 by
        self.dir_prefix = self.settings.get('dir_prefix', 'gatling-%s' % id(self))
        # From method bzt.modules.gatling.GatlingExecutor:prepare, copy code after famous line 309
```

**Create a file *./bztx.py* to wrap command `bzt`:**

```
import signal
import logging
from bzt.cli import main, signal_handler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    main()
```

**Update file *scenario.yml* by using new setting property *dir_prefix* and define new executor class:**

```
modules:
  gatling:
    path:       ./bin/gatling.sh
    class:      extensions.GatlingExecutorExtension
    dir_prefix: my_scenario
    java-opts:  -Dgatling.core.directory.data=./data -Dgatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName=./my_scenario
```

**Finaly, update your Jenkinsfile by replacing *bzt* call with a call to your new file *bztx.py*:**

```
stage('perf') {
  steps {
    sh 'python bztx.py ./taurus/scenario.yml'
    perfReport configType: 'PRT', graphType: 'PRT', ignoreFailedBuilds: true, modePerformancePerTestCase: true, modeThroughput: true, sourceDataFiles: 'results.xml'
    dir ("taurus/results") {
      gatlingArchive()
    }
  }
}
```

That's all and it works for me. Bonus: this solution gives a way to easily extends taurus with your owns plugins ;-)